# Points appear at different location when using google map overlay

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have used vector point from database and also polygon country vectors from database.Points appear with in this country vectors but as I switch to google earth map as base layer the points at smaller zoom level would appear outside boundary where as at other zoom level it would appear inside. I have tried to add projection too but in vain.Do I need to reproject google earth's base layer and How?

```js
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
                    controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),                       
                        new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                    ],                 
             projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
             displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
             numZoomLevels: 21,
             maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508,20037508, 20037508.34)

                });           

                var border = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Border",
                url, 
                {layers: 'GisData:BORDER'}
            );

                var dsBand = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "District Band",
                url, 
                {layers: 'GisData:BND'}
            );                  


                var Site1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Site 1",
                url, 
                {layers: 'GisData:sites', transparent: "true",format: "image/png"}             
            );
                dwnSite3G.setIsBaseLayer(false);

                var Site2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Site 2",
                url, 
                {layers: 'GisData:sites2', transparent: "true",format: "image/png"}             
            );


                var g_pmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Physical",
                {type: G_PHYSICAL_MAP}
                );

                var gmap_gs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Streets" // the default

                );

                var gmap_ghy  = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Hybrid",
                    {type: G_HYBRID_MAP}
                );

                var gmap_gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Satellite",
                    {type: G_SATELLITE_MAP}
                )
```

Comment: Sounds like the same problem I had: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/overlaying-lat-lon-points-on-google-layer-in-openlayers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map options are not correct. To use Google as a base layer you have to pass the following options:

```js
var options = {
   projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
   displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
   numZoomLevels: 21,
   maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508,20037508, 20037508.34)
};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);
```

and set

```js
var googleStreets = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets",
            {'sphericalMercator': true}
        );
```

on the Google Layers.

Documentation for using OpenLayers with a Spherical Mercator projection:

http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html

Comment: I edited my code but all other layers except google earth went red :(

Comment: Have you set Google layers option 'sphericalMercator': true ? Try to create fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can see your code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PVttcr2u and setting 'sphericalMercator': true would make everything empty

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/adB1nq8S

Comment: I changed the code to setcenter but I could not make other base layer except google's appear.

Answer (score 0):

The projection for your layers is EPSG4326 and the one used by google is google mercator ESPG:900913. This might be leading to the changes in the projection system .

Comment: yes I know that but I thought geoserver will reproject it for me. any idea?

Comment: It'll only reproject it if you ask it to, by defining the projections for all of your layers, and if GeoServer can reproject that data type - raster might not work.